# Redirect to another webbsite

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I have two websites https://abc1.com
https://example1.com.

Example1 is an ecommerce site. Let's say in the website a product link is https://example1.com/products/123456.html

Now I'm sharing the product and share link is https://abc1.com/products/123456.html

When user is clicking the link,it should redirect to https://example1.com/products/123456.html.

For a static page manually it is possible for each link.but I want it dynamically. You can understand in an ecommerce site there will be tons of products, constantly updating. So that whatever the product id will be placed with abc.com dynamically it should redirect to example1.com.

I have to redirect via js.like https://abc1.com/probucts/xyz123.html --> to a page where js,text/picture will be -->[redirection] -->  https://example1.com/products/xyz123.html

If anybody can help.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking. If you want the link to go to `example1.com` then just share a link to that URL rather than one to `abc1.com`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: No sir I can't redirect example1.com directly. I have to share with abc1.com

Comment: @henrik.sir I have read that but problem is that dynamically I can't pass the product Id with abc1.com.

Comment: Check .htaccess mod_rewrite

Comment: @Xriuk.can you plz give any example.

Comment: @xriuk, is it possible with JS?

Comment: @Debo with just JS no

Comment: @xriuk, ok. Let's say I have typed abc1.com/products/123 in address bar. Browser will take me to a page (ignoring 404 error) where js will be there and then it will be redirected to the desired page(example1.com/products/123.html). But how to ignor 404 error at first? Is it possible?

Comment: @Debo Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use .htaccess, you need to create a file named `.htaccess` in the root of your `abc1.com` website, with this content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/products/([0-9]+).html$ https://example1.com/products/$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

This redirects every URL like this: https://abc1.com/products/123456.html
to this: https://example1.com/products/123456.html

**EDIT:**

If you need to redirect via JS, you can just rewrite the url to a single page:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/products/([0-9]+).html$ /redirect.html?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

And inside `redirect.html` put the JS redirection code by using the `id` parameter

Comment: You are assuming the OP is running Apache. I do not see why that assumption may be justified in any way.

Comment: @xriuk, thank you very much. It solved 50% of my problem. But you are redirecting directly but for my problem, I have to redirect via js.like https://abc1.com/probucts/xyz123.html --> to a page where js,text/picture will be -->[redirection] -->  https://example1.com/products/xyz123.html

Comment: @Debo  in your js code on https://abc1.com/probucts/xyz123.html  try with   window.location = 'https://example1.com/products/xyz123.html';

Comment: @user889030, for a static page it's possible. But as I said above it's for an ecommerce site. So static page for every link it is not possible.thats why I need your help guys.

Comment: can you try something like this , you will have to inject this few line of js in your footer so that it load on all pages
[code]
let your_new_site_host = ' https://example1.com';
let product_path = document.location.pathname;

window.location = your_new_site_host+product_path;
[/code]

Comment: @xriuk, thanks again. You explained in simple words , and newcomers like me can understand easily. One more question I have against your answer, if abc1.com's link is like https://abc1.com/share/[*****/****] (like - abc1.com/share/products/xyzabz1 or abc1.com/share/vendors/z@12abcwq) and redirect.html file is in a folder named"check" in the server, how to pick id parameter so that redirect url should be https://example1.com/[*****/****]? Same .htaccess code?

Comment: If I understood correctly you could have multiple "sections" (/), then you could use something like this: `RewriteRule ^share/(.+)$ /check/redirect.html?id=$1 [NC,L]` the `id` parameter would be everything after "share/", so: "products/xyzabz1", "vendors/z@12abcwq", ...

Comment: Thank you @xriuk. Will implement and will let you know the result.